# Smallest and largest possible maximum singular value of this product

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, singular-values

Consider the following function of unitary matrices ${\bf U},{\bf V} \in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$:
$$f({\bf U},{\bf V}) = \sigma_\mathrm{max}({\bf AUBVC})$$
whereby $\sigma_\mathrm{max}$ denotes the largest singular value. Everything is real-valued. ${\bf A}\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N},{\bf B}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N},{\bf C}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times O}$ are diagonal matrices with entries in descending order (i.e. the top left element is largest).

I am concerned with the following questions:

1. *[the easy one]* It is quite clear that
   $$\max_{{\bf U},{\bf V}} f({\bf U},{\bf V}) = |A_{1,1} \, B_{1,1} \, C_{1,1}|.$$
   What is the most concise way to prove this rigorously?
2. *[the hard one]* Regarding the minimum value
   $$\min_{{\bf U},{\bf V}} f({\bf U},{\bf V})$$
   can we state a closed-form expression? If not, can we state a good approximation or bound?

Thank you.

Comment: I did some more research: Regarding 1, I think using Theorem 9 from http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/AMEN/2004/040205-3.pdf one can show that $|A_{1,1}B_{1,1}C_{1,1}|$ is an upper bound, and it is easy to see that this bound can be achieved, which would prove that it is the maximum.